# Get data from table where date between given date and 1 week back

Tags: mysql, date, select, datediff

I have database **dbadmin**, table - **tbl_empreimburse** with **fields-emp_id,rem_amount,rem_date**.

I want to retrieve data which comes from given date to a week back.
I tried this query,

```
SELECT SUM(rem_amount),DATEADD(dd, -7, "2012-01-10")  
FROM tbl_empreimburse 
GROUP BY emp_id 
HAVING emp_id='5' AND rem_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -7, "2012-01-10") AND "2012-01-10"
```

It gives me error "**FUNCTION dbadmin.DATEADD does not exist**". Do I need to convert "2012-01-10"  to date format? Any Help, Please?

Comment: So you do want to get records within 1 week constant interval going back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [*SQLFIDDLE reference out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81d48/2). :)

I am not sure why you are using `group by` clause here...

Sample date:

```
ID  AMOUNT  RDATE
1   3400    January, 01 2012 00:00:00+0000
2   5000    January, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000
3   3000    January, 02 2012 00:00:00+0000
5   1000    January, 05 2012 00:00:00+0000
5   2000    January, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000
2   2000    February, 10 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

Query:

```
select * from emp
where id = 5;
```

**here is the query to get sum**

```
select id, sum(amount)
from emp
where rdate between '2012-01-10' - interval 7 day
and '2012-01-10'
and id = 5
;
```

Results:
**all records by employee id = 5**

```
ID  AMOUNT  RDATE
5   1000    January, 05 2012 00:00:00+0000
5   2000    January, 04 2012 00:00:00+0000
```

**sum of amount by employee id = 5**

```
ID  SUM(AMOUNT)
5   3000
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

This query gives result as you have specified for employee id 5 and date period of 7 days.

```
SELECT emp_id, SUM(rem_amount) 
FROM tbl_empreimburse 
WHERE emp_id='5' AND DATEDIFF('2012-12-31', rem_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 7;
```

**OR**

Below query gives you all employee data.

```
SELECT emp_id, SUM(rem_amount) 
FROM tbl_empreimburse 
GROUP BY emp_id 
HAVING DATEDIFF('2012-12-31', rem_date) BETWEEN 0 AND 7;
```